# Dropdown not triggered when using partial view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in my index:

```
<div class="btn-group wkt-btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn share dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SHARE
      <span class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:16px;"></span>
      </button>
  <% render partial: 'booksocial',  locals: {book: book} %>
</div>
```

Then in my partial:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu wk-social">
<li>
    <div class="jssocials-share jssocials-share-email">
        <a href="#" onclick="PrintImage('<%= image_url(book.book_image.to_c)%>'); return false;" class="jssocials-share-link" style="background-color: purple; width: 73px;">Print</a>
        <i class="jssocials-share-logo"></i>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="jssocials-share jssocials-share-email">
        <a href="mailto:?Subject=I Like BIg Books&amp;Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 http://books.com/book/<%= book.book_name %>" class="jssocials-share-link">
            <i class="fa fa-at jssocials-share-logo"></i><span class="jssocials-share-label">E-mail</span>
        </a>
    </div>

</li>
```

The page is rendering with the dropdown button but it's actually not rendering the dropdown options. Is there something in my code preventing the list from rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy answer that I'm surprised no one chimed in with. I'm not actually outputting the partial at the moment.

```
<%= render partial: 'booksocial',  locals: {book: book} %>
```